# When someone puts your integrity/reliability "in doubt"

Tags: phrase-requests

Assume a scenario in which you talk with someone and then he puts your integrity/reliability "in doubt".
Meaning: He doubts that you are truly reliable/innocent/trustworthy.

So you want to say to him a phrase that means "Do you really put my integrity in doubt?" or something similar.
I'm quite certain that this kind of phrase exists, but I don't remember what it is.

Comment: Are you calling me a liar?

Comment: There's also the [medieval glove slap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel#Offense_and_satisfaction) :) .

Answer (score 11):

Consider, *Are you **questioning** my integrity?*

> question: to make a question of; doubt : they questioned our sincerity [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/question)

Answer (score 7):

Not so much a phrase as a verb that is useful in expressing that meaning: ***[impugn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impugn)***:

> to criticize (a person’s character, intentions, etc.) by suggesting that someone is not honest and should not to be trusted.

—as in—

> - Are you impugning my integrity?
> - Do you really mean to impugn my integrity?

Usage note: although from the definition linked, or parts of it, one might think to say “Are you impugning *me”?* this transitive verb is more usually found with *character, integrity, reliability,* or *motives* for object.

Answer (score 6):

You can say

> Are you doubting my integrity?

Answer (score 4):

*[Casting aspersions](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/aspersion)* is another option here.

Are you *casting aspersions*?

> **aspersion**
>
> An aspersion is a disparaging remark. It almost invariably appears as a plural, following the word "cast" — when you
> cast aspersions on someone, you are questioning their abilities or
> doubting them.

Answer (score 2):

*[Discredit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/discredit)* or *[discount](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/discount)* might work:

> Are you *discrediting* me? Do you *discount* my integrity?

Phrases include:

> Are you *casting doubt on me*?
>
> Do you *take me for a liar/cheat*?

Answer (score 2):

"We found a dozen faked invoices hidden in Jim's desk; these invoices put Jim's integrity in doubt". That's how I would usually use this; when some finding seems to show evidence that Jim might not be an honest person, that puts Jim's honesty or integrity in doubt.

"I talked to Jack who made some interesting remarks about Jim, and now I doubt Jim's integrity". I doubt his integrity means I personally believe that Jim is not honest.

"I think I caught him lying, so I question Jim's integrity". This means it's more than just a personal belief, I am making a suggestion for everyone to hear that Jim might be a dishonest person.

The question "Do you really put my integrity in doubt?" would therefore be a bit strange. "Does X put someone's integrity in doubt?" means "Is X really evidence about someone's lack of integrity?" Much more usual would be "Do you really doubt my integrity?" meaning "Do you really think I am a dishonest person?" or "Do you really question my integrity?" meaning "Are you really suggesting to other people that I might be a dishonest person?"